# Pdo Error Catching Try/Catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After looking into using try catch blocks for my Pdo statements is it really a benefit? Does this just slow your code down?

I believe that there should be a try catch around the connection command in case the database connection fails. But does there really need to be try catch around each pre prepared statement? These should never change and never really error out.

Any thoughts?

I'm using Php and MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit to this:

```
try {
  // exec statement
  // exec statement
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // do nothing
}
```

If you aren't going to do anything with the error and provide a reasonable solution, then you may as well let the exception bubble up to the application's main "something went wrong" error page.

But you may want to do this:

```
// begin transaction
try {
  // exec statement
  // exec statement
  // commit transaction
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // rollback transaction
  // handle error or rethrow $e; 
}
```

And prepared statements can throw exceptions. Perhaps a unique key is violated, or a foreign key constraint is, etc.

But the main point is, you don't use exceptions to hide or silence errors. You use them to catch an error, process it intelligently, and continue on accordingly.